# Any way to maintain particle color when converting to a mesh?

Tags: texturing, materials, particles, eevee-render-engine

Ive got a particle system set up to use a plane as the render object and the plane is using the particle instancer texture coordinates so that the particle color is determined from where they emit.[image: particles and render object]

When i convert the system all of the particle meshes just turn black.[image]

Is there any way to make them maintain their color when i convert them? Or an alternative way to make a collection of meshes adopt their color from the points on another mesh? If there is an option that works with eevee that would be even better.